# How can I Autoupdate Vlookup Links when the other workbook is open?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, auto-update

I have two workbooks, **"Test1"** and **"Test2"** each with a sheet inside. The code is inside the **"Test1"** workbook, inside the ***"ThisWorkbook"*** module.

I have a Vlookup in the sheet *"Mytest1"* inside the **"Test1"** workbook, that simply does a Vlookup with workbook **"Test2"** inside sheet *"Mytest2"*. Both workbooks are password protected, I am having an issue where if I have the workbook **"Test2"** opened on another computer, I get a prompt to "Enter Password" for **"Test2"** when I open my **"Test1"** workbook. I need to have the Vlookups autoupdate without any prompts for password entries or the second workbook opening up.

I have posted screenshots below of both workbooks and code, alongside the code itself. Please edit or ask me any questions to clarify anything.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

          Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\FILEPATH\Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf", Updatelinks:=3
          ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

[image: Code inside the "Test1" workbook]

[image: "Test1" workbook]
[image: "Test2" workbook]

Answer (score 0):

I dont have time to test, but will later.  I'd try rewriting VLOOKUP as a wrapper round VLOOKUP like so

```
Function VLOOKUP_BYPASS(LookFor As Variant, Rng As Excel.Range, lngCol As Long) As Variant

Dim strWorkbook As String

strWorkbook = Rng.Parent.Parent.Name

If WORKBOOKOPEN(strWorkbook) Then
    VLOOKUP_BYPASS = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(LookFor, Rng, lngCol, False)
Else
    VLOOKUP_BYPASS = "NA"
End If

End Function

Function WORKBOOKOPEN(strWorkbookName As String) As Boolean

WORKBOOKOPEN = False

Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

On Error GoTo eHandle

Set wb = Workbooks(strWorkbookName)
WORKBOOKOPEN = True

Exit Function

eHandle:


End Function
```

Comment: I copy and pasted the code into my module "ThisWorkbook", the only thing that seems to be happening is that the prompt to enter the password for the "Test 2" is now gone, but the vlookup is not autoupdating now.

Comment: Have you changed your vlookups to be the new VLOOKUP_BYPASS function

Comment: Hello Nathan, do I just copy and paste that code just the way it is? or do I need to make some modifications (please let me know, I am still new)

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, I simply made the file I am using to reference my Vlookup (**"Test 2"** Workbook) open up as a read-only file!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\FILEPATH \Databases\Test 2.xlsm", Password:="Swarf", Updatelinks:=3,ReadOnly:=True

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```